How to publish a page in Wagtail CMS?
I'm trying to publish a page in Wagtail CMS, but I'm having trouble with the publishing process. I can access the Wagtail admin interface, but I can't seem to find the "Publish" button in the preview mode. The root page ("Welcome to your new Wagtail site!") is visible, but the page I created is not.
Here are the steps I've taken:

Created a new page in the Wagtail admin interface.
Edited the page content and saved it as a draft.
Tried to preview the page, but there's no "Publish" button in the preview mode.
Tried going to the "Pages" section in the admin interface, and edited the slug as test1 in the Promote tab.

When I go to the link with slug, I get the following error:
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://chat-jj.pythonanywhere.com/test1/
Raised by: wagtail.views.serve
Using the URLconf defined in PyChat.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:


admin/
documents/
_util/authenticate_with_password/<int:page_view_restriction_id>/<int:page_id>/ [name='wagtailcore_authenticate_with_password']
_util/login/ [name='wagtailcore_login']
^((?:[\w\-]+/)*)$ [name='wagtail_serve']
The current path, test1/, matched the last one.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.


I'm using Wagtail version 6.0.2 and Django version 5.0.4.
Can someone please guide me through the correct process of publishing a page in Wagtail CMS? I'm stuck and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Please let me know if you need any additional information or clarification.
I was expecting the new page to be published and accessible on the website after following the publishing process described in the Wagtail documentation. However, the page is not visible, and I'm unsure why the publishing process is not working as intended.
The root page ("Welcome to your new Wagtail site!") is visible, but the new page I created is not.

Some ideas. In the editing interface for your page in Wagtail admin, make sure the page is not only saved but also published. In the Wagtail admin, go to the Pages section and click on your page to open the editing interface. After editing, instead of previewing, look for the Publish button at the bottom part of the page editor (next to the Save Draft button).
In Wagtail, pages need to be properly nested within the site's hierarchy to be accessible. Ensure that your new page (test1) is a child of the correct root page. The root page should ideally be set to a page that acts as the homepage or top-level directory for your site. You can check and configure this in the Wagtail admin under the Pages section.
The error suggests a mismatch in expected URL patterns. In your Wagtail's root urls.py file, verify that Wagtail's serving mechanism (wagtail_serve) is correctly configured to catch all relevant URLs.
It should typically look something like this:
from wagtail.core import urls as wagtail_urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),
    re_path(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),
]


Christian's information is all good. The only other thing I would check is what you have in your "Sites". Even if you are only going to run one site from your Wagtail install, you need to have a record in the sites table with the correct hostname, port, and your site's root page. Here is the sites page from bakerydemo on my local install. 
